# Image data loss when converting to byte array

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, memorystream

I'm trying to use a `MemoryStream` to turn an image into a byte array, however, the image looks different when I recover it.

I made a simple `Form` app to show the issue. I'm using the google chrome Icon for this example:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(3876); // found pid manually
var image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(process.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap();
pictureBox1.Image = image;

byte[] imageBytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Result:

[image: image before and image after]

Any idea what I'm missing here?

---

**Update** I was able to get the proper bytes using the following code:

```
var converter = new ImageConverter();
var imageBytes = (byte[]) converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
```

Would still like to know whats up with the Memory stream though..

Comment: Try to use the 32bit format like PNG. The circle needs probably transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Icons are complicated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx).  When they contain transparent parts, converting to BMP or JPG [almost always seems to end badly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37261353/1070452).  You also dont need `ImageConverter` it is doing almost what your code does without the BMP conversion:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(844); // found pid manually
var image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(process.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap();
pb1.Image = image;

byte[] imageBytes; 

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{ 
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);        // PNG for transparency
    ms.Position = 0;
    pb2.Image = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);                
}
```

[ImageConverter Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ImageConverter.cs,813657c18c4b78e5)